# Redirect output to a file permission denied?

Tags: unix, curl, permission-denied, io-redirection

I want to do a simple redirection. When I do

```
sudo curl <insert link here> > a.txt
```

I want to take all of the data outputted by the curl into a.txt. However, I keep getting an error saying

```
a.txt: Permission denied
```

Would anyone have any idea how to get around this? I've tried looking online by doing

```
sudo bash -c curl <insert link here> > a.txt
```

and that displays the same error. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

The privilege elevation only applies to the `curl` process (and, in the second example, the child shell) itself, not to your (parent) shell, and therefore not to the redirection.

One solution is to do the redirection within the child shell itself:

```
sudo bash -c "curl $LINK >a.txt"
```

Another, fairly idiomatic option is to use `tee`:

```
curl $LINK | sudo tee a.txt >/dev/null
```

For `curl` specifically, you can also make the process itself write to the file directly:

```
sudo curl -o a.txt $LINK
```

Comment: Hm, every time I try to do one of the commands, I get an error saying curl: (7) couldn't connect to host. Might you know why?

Comment: Curl can't connect to the server. Maybe it's down or there's a firewall or your network settings are screwy or you mistyped the URL.It's not related to the problem you asked about.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and it's because the folder of a.txt isn't writable to you. Either `chmod/chown` it or put it to a writable folder will solve the problem.

Hope this helps!